# Spring.NET + NHibernate - Multiple (Distinct) Databases with OpenSessionInView

Tags: asp.net, nhibernate, spring.net, multiple-databases, open-session-in-view

In my web application, I have 2 totally different databases - one that's being used mostly by a CMS from which we'd like to get page information on non CMS pages on the same website, & one that contains totally different data.

Is it possible to use Spring.NET's Open Session In View module with multiple session factories for both of those databases, so in this case I have 2 objects defined in spring.config of type `Spring.Data.NHibernate.LocalSessionFactoryObject`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are talking about the same situation as the user in this forum post

http://forum.springframework.net/showthread.php?p=20720

Let me know if that solutions works out for you.

Cheers,
Mark

Comment: Hi Mark, Thank you very much for your very informative answer.  Your solution above unfortunately didn't quite work as there's only a no parameter constructor in OpenSessionInViewModule.  However, I did go around this by creating a copy of OpenSessionInView in my project & that did the trick, so I will accept your answer.