# How to support multi datasources with OpenSessionInView by Spring.NET/NHibernate?

Tags: asp.net, nhibernate, spring.net

I found some tip from [Spring.NET + NHibernate - Multiple (Distinct) Databases with OpenSessionInView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3457911/spring-net-nhibernate-multiple-distinct-databases-with-opensessioninview), but it dosen't work for me, need your help to identify what's going wrong.

my project is based on ASP.NET/Spring.NET(OpenSessionInView)/NHibernate, and we need to manupilate an external database, so we want to support multi datasources in OSIV pattern.

what we have done by ref the above links:

(1) Create a subclass of Spring.Data.NHibernate.Support.OpenSessionInViewModule

```
namespace MyProject.Infrastructure.NHibernate
{
    public class ExtDbOpenSessionInViewModule : OpenSessionInViewModule
    {
    }
}
```

(2) Confige the OSIV in web.config

here is my configurations for Spring.NET and NHibernate integration:

```
<!-- Spring Web Support and OSIV for NHibernate -->
<add name="Spring" type="Spring.Context.Support.WebSupportModule, Spring.Web"/>
<add name="OpenSessionInViewOnLocalDb" type="Spring.Data.NHibernate.Support.OpenSessionInViewModule, Spring.Data.NHibernate32"/>
<add name="OpenSessionInViewOnExtDb" type="MyProject.Infrastructure.NHibernate.ExtDbOpenSessionInViewModule, MyProject.Infrastructure"/>

<!-- NHibernate SessionFactory in OSIV-->
<appSettings>
    <add key="Spring.Data.NHibernate.Support.OpenSessionInViewModule.SessionFactoryObjectName" value="LocalDbSessionFactory"/>
    <add key="MyProject.Infrastructure.NHibernate.ExtDbOpenSessionInViewModule.SessionFactoryObjectName" value="ExtDbSessionFactory"/>
</appSettings>
```

When we were running it, the system says:

```
No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here
```

we found that SessionFactoryObject in any Repository object is null.

the logs was like these:

```
2012-09-13 10:29:19,017 [13] DEBUG MyProject.Infrastructure.NHibernate.ExtDbOpenSessionInViewModule [(null)] - Trying to close SessionScope
2012-09-13 10:29:19,018 [13] DEBUG MyProject.Infrastructure.NHibernate.ExtDbOpenSessionInViewModule [(null)] - Only participated Hibernate Session - doing nothing
2012-09-13 10:29:19,030 [13] DEBUG MyProject.Infrastructure.NHibernate.ExtDbOpenSessionInViewModule [(null)] - Participating in existing Hibernate SessionFactory
2012-09-13 10:29:19,033 [14] DEBUG MyProject.Infrastructure.NHibernate.ExtDbOpenSessionInViewModule [(null)] - Participating in existing Hibernate SessionFactory
2012-09-13 10:29:19,043 [13] DEBUG MyProject.Infrastructure.NHibernate.ExtDbOpenSessionInViewModule [(null)] - Trying to close SessionScope
2012-09-13 10:29:19,055 [14] DEBUG MyProject.Infrastructure.NHibernate.ExtDbOpenSessionInViewModule [(null)] - Trying to close SessionScope
2012-09-13 10:29:19,062 [13] DEBUG MyProject.Infrastructure.NHibernate.ExtDbOpenSessionInViewModule [(null)] - Only participated Hibernate Session - doing nothing
2012-09-13 10:29:19,071 [14] DEBUG MyProject.Infrastructure.NHibernate.ExtDbOpenSessionInViewModule [(null)] - Only participated Hibernate Session - doing nothing
2012-09-13 10:29:19,117 [13] DEBUG MyProject.Infrastructure.NHibernate.ExtDbOpenSessionInViewModule [(null)] - Participating in existing Hibernate SessionFactory
2012-09-13 10:29:19,122 [13] DEBUG MyProject.Infrastructure.NHibernate.ExtDbOpenSessionInViewModule [(null)] - Trying to close SessionScope
2012-09-13 10:29:19,126 [13] DEBUG MyProject.Infrastructure.NHibernate.ExtDbOpenSessionInViewModule [(null)] - Only participated Hibernate Session - doing nothing
2012-09-13 10:29:19,130 [13] DEBUG MyProject.Infrastructure.NHibernate.ExtDbOpenSessionInViewModule [(null)] - Participating in existing Hibernate SessionFactory
2012-09-13 10:29:19,132 [13] DEBUG MyProject.Infrastructure.NHibernate.ExtDbOpenSessionInViewModule [(null)] - Trying to close SessionScope
2012-09-13 10:29:19,132 [13] DEBUG MyProject.Infrastructure.NHibernate.ExtDbOpenSessionInViewModule [(null)] - Only participated Hibernate Session - doing nothing
2012-09-13 10:29:21,347 [14] DEBUG MyProject.Infrastructure.NHibernate.ExtDbOpenSessionInViewModule [(null)] - Participating in existing Hibernate SessionFactory
2012-09-13 10:29:21,441 [14] INFO  Spring.Aop.Framework.AutoProxy.InfrastructureAdvisorAutoProxyCreator [(null)] - Candidate advisor [ObjectFactoryTransactionAttributeSourceAdvisor: advice object 'Spring.Transaction.Interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0'] rejected for targetType [ASP.pages_sysmgmt_debug_aspx]
2012-09-13 10:29:21,457 [14] DEBUG MyProject.Infrastructure.NHibernate.ExtDbOpenSessionInViewModule [(null)] - Trying to close SessionScope
2012-09-13 10:29:21,458 [14] DEBUG MyProject.Infrastructure.NHibernate.ExtDbOpenSessionInViewModule [(null)] - Only participated Hibernate Session - doing nothing
```

Oops! we are realy stuck by it.

Comment: This [question and answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10981625/nhibernate-spring-net-lazy-loading-failed-no-session/10982363#10982363) might be of help.

Answer (score 1):

Having asked the question you refer to & have used a solution based on it for over 2 years, I may be able to help you.

While not ideal, rather than subclass `OpenSessionInViewModule`, you'll need to copy it [from Spring.NET's source](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-net/blob/master/src/Spring/Spring.Data.NHibernate/Data/NHibernate/Support/OpenSessionInViewModule.cs).  When doing this, make sure you make one alteration to the default constructor.  It will look something like this:

```
public MyOpenSessionInViewModule() : 
       base("appSettings", typeof(OpenSessionInViewModule), false)
```

The type on the second parameter to the call on the base class should be your newly copied class - for example:

```
public MyOpenSessionInViewModule() : 
       base("appSettings", typeof(MyOpenSessionInViewModule), false)
```

Other than that, everything else on your question seems to be correct.  Let me know how this goes.